# Let's advertise Writers on other SE sites!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Stack Exchange sites that have graduated can add *community ads* to the rotation of ads shown on the front page (that place where you sometimes see ads for random other SE sites).  These ads are voted on by members of their communities, and if enough voters agree that the ad would be welcome on their site, it's added.

We already have some ads on other sites, thanks to Neil, but let's collect them all together in one place -- for community visibility, and because these ads have to be reposted each year so having one meta question here to work from will be helpful in the future.

Please use answers here to collect ads we've proposed on other sites, or ads you would *like* to propose on other sites.  Indicate the site and, if it's been proposed, link to the proposal on the other site's meta.

Here's the required format for ad submissions:

> **Image requirements**
>   The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
>   Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
>   Must be GIF or PNG No animated GIFs
>   Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
>
> All answers should be in the exact form of:
>
> > `[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]`
> >
> > `[1]: http://image-url    [2]: http://clickthrough-url`

The link could be to our main site, to a tag, or to a specific question.

Let's get ourselves some more publicity.  Can you help?

Comment: Formatting requirements have changed since I asked this question.  Also, we changed our name.  See [the 2018 post](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/1993) for the latest!

Answer (score 6):

From Neil:

[image: Writing exercise chat]

[Currently live on Sci-Fi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6497/32756).

Answer (score 5):

From Neil:

[image: Writing exercise chat]

[Currently live on English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6848/8816).

Answer (score 5):

[image: Ad for Writers]

[Proposed on Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1735/3928), links to [academic-writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing).

Comment: These look like they're soliciting writers; I'd change the title to "Writers.SE".

Answer (score 4):

From Neil:

[image: Ad for Writers site]

[Proposed on Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3158/325), links to [business-writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-writing).

Comment: These look like they're soliciting writers; I'd change the title to "Writers.SE".