# Let's advertise Writers.SE on other sites, 2016 edition

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In 2015 I [suggested we advertise our site selectively on other SE sites](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1003/1993) and people generated several ads to run on Science Fiction, English Language & Learners, Academia, and The Workplace.  It's 2016 now, which means we have to submit ads again, but first we have a little work to do as the size requirements have changed.

Please use answers here to collect ads you would like to propose on other sites (graduated sites only). Indicate the site where the ad should run, and if you've already proposed it, link here to the meta post on their site so we can follow its progress.

SE Image requirements:

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if retina.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 40 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border surrounding it.

An ad could link to our main site, to a tag, or to a specific question.

Let's get ourselves some more publicity. Can you help?

Comment: You've now seen my ad-making ability (*cough*).  You can do better; I know you can.

Answer (score 4):

[image: ad for Worldbuilding]

[Submitted on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2903/28)

Comment: Thanks @Neil.  If it looks like Comic Sans -- that wouldn't have occurred to me but now that you've mentioned it I can see why you think so -- then we should choose a different font.  I'm totally fine with that, and I should not have gone ahead and submitted anyway (I've removed that).  I was thinking iterative development -- get something queued up and tweak it -- but I was too eager.

Comment: @NeilFein by the way, you made some great ads for last year and I hope you're planning to redo those for the new size.

Comment: I uploaded a new design; if you don't like it, please revert and I'll try again. I tried to keep the same concept and just used an architect-like font.

Comment: And absolutely, I'll get on redoing all the ads in the new format.

Comment: @NeilFein looks great, thanks!  Anybody see any problem with going ahead and submitting it to Worldbuilding?  If we come up with a better one we can replace, but our meta activity has been light lately so maybe we don't want to wait for a bunch of votes here?  On the other hand, any objection is enough to say "no" at this point.

Comment: I'd just submit it. You're right that meta activity is light here.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Come to Writer's Chat]

[Submitted and approved on EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7612/8360)

[Submitted on RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6027/10964)